# Chaining a clone and a find

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clone my template (this is just a tr), then inside the template find a td (this.titleRow) then add text to it.

The problem I have is that the below clones the template, finds the table row, inserts the text but as I have used find, only the title row td is appended from the clone, other td's are not.

How can I do this but keep the command chained?

```
$(this.tBody).append(this.template.clone().find(this.titleRow).text('John Smith');
```

Comment: It's *possible* to do it with chaining by using `.end()` but I think that just makes it less readable. I'd use two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain them as a single line if you use `appendTo` (instead of `append`) as it retains the cloned object as the return value:

```
this.template.clone().appendTo(this.tBody).find(this.titleRow).text('John Smith');
```